# Variable variables syntax and for loop issues

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I'm using variables as keys in an array. I understand that won't work with the superglobals.
The following code snippet will run the correct number of times, but only picks up data on the first iteration. Do I have a variable variable syntax problem, or a loop problem? Can anyone clarify this for a newbie?

```
$php_postData = $_POST; 

$php_totalPanels = $_SESSION['totalPanels']; 

for ($php_count=1;$php_count<$php_totalPanels; $php_count++){
echo "<div class='individualQuote'>";

$php_currentItemWidth = 'width_' . $php_count; 
$php_currentItemHeight = 'height_' . $php_count;        
$php_currentItemDescription = 'description_' . $php_count;
$php_currentItemPartNumber = 'partNumber_' . $php_count;
$php_currentItemLexan = 'lexan_' . $php_count;
$php_currentItemVinyl = 'vinyl_' . $php_count;
$php_currentItemPolyester = 'polyester_' . $php_count;

if ( isset($php_postData[$php_currentItemDescription]) ){
echo "<p><span class='em'>Label Name: </span>" . $php_postData[$php_currentItemDescription] . "</p>";   
}

if ( isset($php_postData[$php_currentItemPartNumber]) ){
echo "<p><span class='em'>Part Number: </span>" . $php_postData[$php_currentItemPartNumber] . "</p>";   
}


if ( isset($php_postData[$php_currentItemLexan]) && $php_postData[$php_currentItemLexan] != '0' ) {
echo "<p><span class='em'>Material: </span>" . $php_postData[$php_currentItemLexan] . "</p>";
} 

if ( isset($php_postData[$php_currentItemVinyl]) && $php_postData[$php_currentItemVinyl] != '0'){
echo "<p><span class='em'>Material: </span>" . $php_postData[$php_currentItemVinyl] . "</p>";
} 

if ( isset($php_postData[$php_currentItemPolyester]) && $php_postData[$php_currentItemPolyester] != '0'){
echo "<p><span class='em'>Material: </span>" . $php_postData[$php_currentItemPolyester] . "</p>";
}

if ( isset($php_postData[$php_currentItemWidth]) && isset($php_postData[$php_currentItemHeight]) ){
echo "<p><span class='em'>Size: </span>" . $php_postData[$php_currentItemWidth] . " x " . $php_postData[$php_currentItemHeight] . "</p>";
 }  

echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: The following code snippet ... Where ?

Comment: `"that won't work with the superglobals"`.  *What* won't work with superglobals?  Can you edit in the code you are using?

Comment: first thing first add session_start() at the top of ur page !!

Comment: So, what's the problem here?  You're *not* using "variable variables".  Using "variables as keys" works just fine with superglobals.  Where did you get the idea that it didn't?  Chances are, you just need to add `session_start()` so that `$_SESSION` will be available.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty session_start() is a given, done that.

Comment: @user1681975: So, did that fix it?  What's the problem here?  You say "only picks up data on the first iteration", what does that mean?  What do you see echoed to the screen?  What is `$php_totalPanels`?  Maybe you need to do `for ($php_count=1; $php_count <= $php_totalPanels; $php_count++){`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat php manual says $_POST[ $something ] won't work. I've read this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @RocketHazmat: session_start() was already there, not the problem. $php_totalPanels is a counter the form is in a jquery accordion. For each accordion panel I want to run this loop. If it runs 3 times, I see the 3 divs echoed to the page. The first has data printed to the screen. The remaining 3 have no data contents just the border around the div showing that it is indeed there. The loop runs the correct number of times using $php_count < $php_totalPanels rather than $php_count <= $php_totalPanels

Comment: @user1681975: `$_POST[$something]` works just fine.  You've misunderstood that page.  It's about "variable variables".  You are *not* using that here.  Variable variables is when you do this:  `$myVar = 6;  $varName = 'myVar';  echo $$varName;`.  Notice the `$$`.  That's a variable variable.  What you are doing here is just accessing an array key with a variable, it's *completely* different.

Comment: Does `for ($php_count=1; $php_count <= $php_totalPanels; $php_count++){` help?  What value does `$php_totalPanels` have?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I agree I may have misunderstood the php manual page. However, when I tried $_POST[$something] it did not work.

Comment: @user1681975: What is `$something`?  Are you sure `$_POST` has that key?  `$_POST[$something]` is correct syntax.

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($_POST);`?  That may be the key to answering this question.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I've done print_r($_POST) it contains all the data I need. There are multiple keys in the array like $_POST['description_1'] and $_POST['description_2'] thats why I used a  counter to add the number after an underscore and set it to a variable. The loop should update the count and variable each time through. Using $_Post[$something] retrieved no data. moving post to a non-superglobal array picks up one set of data but no more.

Answer (score 1):

Could you possibly give an example of the data you are posting in?

Looking at the code your loop starts at 1 and continues while it is lower than the totalPanels value. If you are only posting in an array that is has a 2 sets of data then only one will get printed out. Perhaps your loop should run until the count is lower-than-or-equal-to the totalPanels E.g:

```
for ($php_count=1;$php_count<=$php_totalPanels; $php_count++){...}
```

Or perhaps you mean to have the loop count start at zero E.g.:

```
for ($php_count=0;$php_count<$php_totalPanels; $php_count++){...}
```

I think either of these should make your code run on all values being posted in.

Comment: I've tried this. It changes the number of times the loop runs, but doesn't help with picking up the missing data. As written, the loop starts and stops where I need it to.